# ZF2 config/autoload folder content (ConfigGlobPaths)

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to init an zf2 application to use classes, services and some params from that in an old php application.
I've already included ZF2 and also the application into the old php app with the autoloading of the composer. Many parts are working but the config files of the config/autoload folder are not included. I've tried to search the part at the sources but can't find the part, where the "ConfigGlobPaths" are added/merged to the config.
Do i have to "run" the application? I just wanted to "init" it to use the services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have something wrong with your app root folder, or with the paths that you define in you `application.config.php` to point to the config files.

This is a project-wide issue so it is hard to figure out how to fix it from here. 
Anyways, if you need to know where in the code that files are supposed to be merged, you can start taking a look at:

- `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener.php`
- `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ListenerOptions.php`

Comment: I've already had a look at these part of ZF2 but now i've found the part, where zf2 is searching for the autoload config-files. It's in Zend\Stdlib\Glob::systemGlob using PHP Function glob(). The path was wrong, i've debugged it and changed it to the correct one. thanks anyway!